# Cytoscape.js collapse all incoming and outgoing nodes

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

I've seen this example [Images and breadthfirst layout](https://gist.github.com/maxkfranz/aedff159b0df05ccfaa5) where the clicked node collapses the outgoing nodes. I want to collapse all outgoing as well as incoming nodes. I've tried to write another (similar) method which uses source in place of the target (in the original method).

I then try to call the two methods in succession, but the code always hangs. Could you please tell me how should I collapse all (incoming/outgoing) nodes?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`eles.incomers()`](http://js.cytoscape.org/#nodes.incomers) and [`eles.outgoers()`](http://js.cytoscape.org/#nodes.outgoers) to do DAG traversals.  You can toggle their visibility with a class in your stylesheet.

Comment: Thanks Max. I tried using nodes.successors and the predecessors method, but for some of the nodes returned (by the above calls), I was getting undefined for nodes.connectedEdges. I'll try out the above calls too but don't the successors already give me outgoer's outgoers etc.?

Comment: Yes, those are the recursive versions for convenience